# Laravel 4.2 application occurs unnecessary redirection after uploading live server

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, redirect, laravel-routing

My laravel(4.2) application is working fine on localhost(xampp). But after uploading into live server when trying to login, it is showing a blank page with a message saying "redirecting to my home url". It also throws a login error

Sorry for my weak English. Please help me. I am attaching my htaccess below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Here is my Controller function.

```
public function adminLoginCheck() {
$validation_rule = array(
    'username' => array('required', 'min:5', 'max:50'),
    'password' => array('required', 'min:6', 'max:50')
);
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validation_rule);
// Validation Check
if ($validation->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validation);
} // After Validation Authentication start
else {
    $athentication = Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input :: get('username'), 'password' => Input :: get('password')));
    // When Authentication True
    if ($athentication) { 
        $rememberme = Input::get('remember');
        if(!empty($rememberme)){
            //Remember Login data
           Auth::loginUsingId(Auth::user()->id,true);
        }
        //Redrict to the Target page
        return Redirect::intended('adminDashboard');
    } else {
        //Redrict Login Form with Authentication error massege.
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('authentication_error', 'Username or Password is not valid!');
    }
}
```

}

My Auth filter is given below:

```
Route::filter('auth', function(){if (Auth::guest()){
if (Request::ajax())
{
    return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
}
else
{
    return Redirect::guest('login');
}  }  })
```

All of the blade templates are available.I am not understanding why the blank page is appearing with the redirecting message.Even when submitting login without inputting

> username and password
>   Here is the live url http://noveltyshop.tech-novelty.com/
>   user:admin pass:pass

My route:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'UsersController@adminLoginForm'));
Route::post('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@adminLoginCheck'));
Route::get('/adminDashboard', array('as' => 'adminDashboard', 'uses' => 'UsersController@adminDashboard')); 
Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getLogOut')); 
Route::get('/updateUserProfileForm', array('as' => 'updateUserProfileForm', 'uses' => 'UsersController@updateUserProfileForm'));
Route::post('/updateUserProfile', array('as' => 'updateUserProfile', 'uses' => 'UsersController@updateUserProfile'));
```

> UsersController@adminDashboard

```
public function adminDashboard() {
    return View::make('admin.pages.admin_dashboard')->with('title', 'AdminDashboard');
}
```

Comment: Can you update your routes and your controller too  ?

Comment: Yes I am updating my routes.

Comment: After deleting my comment this still showing to me. Why?

Comment: That answer will be visible only to you .. No worries ;)

Comment: Can you show what is inside `UsersController@adminDashboard` ?

Comment: Updated UsersController@adminDashboard

Comment: Just for testing.. Whats the output for this `public function adminDashboard() {
    return 1;
}`

Comment: All are ok in my local host. But problem is occurs after uploading to the server.

Comment: Ahmm,, Let's fix that it should not more change..

Comment: You got the same output in server too ?

Comment: Yes same output in the server also.

Comment: Ok, For testing can you have your  `admin_dashboard.blade.php` file inside views folder and change to  `return View::make('admin_dashboard')->with('title', 'AdminDashboard');` and tell what happens ?

Comment: Yes problem solved !! Thank you so much. Really you are an Excellent  Guy.

Comment: You're welcome.. Kindly click the tick icon near my answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Laravel 4.2

You shall handle this in your Controller.

Here's the default way that we deal with

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return Redirect::intended('yourTargetPageAfterLogin');
}
```

In the auth filter you shall have this

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
});
```

**Note :**  Make sure you have the blades as you defined in your Controller

**Suggestion :** Why not [upgrade](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade) to [5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) ?